# Saturation curve with geom_step in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have two problems: I would like to create a graph with multiple lines by adding the values in the columns stepwise (should kind of end up looking like multiple saturation curves). I think geom_step in the ggplot2 package should work. However, I don't know how to add the values in the columns as I go and I don't know how to add multiple lines (I will have over 100 lines) therefore both steps should be automated in some way. 
This data set shows my data, only contains the first 3 columns and the first 13 lines.

```
a<-c(0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1)
b<-c(0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1)
c<-c(0,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1)
df<-data.frame(a,b,c)
```

Can anyone help me? I have no idea where to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking for cumulative sums of the data, the `cumsum()` function will do it for you.

It isn't completely clear to me what you're looking for, but this might take care of it:

```
a<-c(0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1)
b<-c(0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1)
c<-c(0,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1)
df2<-data.frame(a,b,c)

df3 <- df2 %>% 
  mutate_all(cumsum) %>% 
  rename_all(paste0, 'x') %>% 
  cbind(df2) %>% 
  mutate(row = row_number()) %>%
  pivot_longer(ax:c)

ggplot(df3) + 
  geom_step(aes(x = row, y = value, color = name))
```

The data was reshaped to longer data for ease of plotting.  Original data was left in as well, those are the lines that stay near the bottom of the graph.

The output:
[image]